# How Do Native South Americans Pronounce Quinoa?

Tags: pronunciation

## Question:

Are there any ***video recordings*** of Native South Americans, (Andeans), pronouncing "Quinoa"? - to hopefully preserve some of the cultural history behind Quinoa?

---

**According to [Wikipedia on Quinoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinoa#History_and_culture):**

> Quinoa was first domesticated ***by Andean peoples*** around 3,000 to 4,000 years ago. It has been an important staple in the ***Andean cultures*** where the plant is indigenous but relatively obscure in the rest of the world. ***The Incas***, who held the crop to be sacred, referred to it as ***chisaya mama*** or "mother of all grains"

Comment: The word derives from Quechua (Cuzco-Collao) *kiwña*; it's pronounced the way it's spelled, and I doubt there are any recordings from real speakers of the word online.

Comment: @user6726 What do you mean, pronounced the way it's spelt? Is it /kiwɲa/?

Comment: Yes, if you use IPA.

Comment: @user6726 everything is [online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6L218_jZspY) somewhere!

Comment: In Brazil, we say like "keenoah"

Comment: Just wondering: Why would the pronunciation of a word in *one* language "resolve a pronunciation debate once and for all" in *another*, completely unrelated language? From what we know about loanword phonology, the argument "they pronounce it like so-and-so, and we'd better try to speak like them" is only a very weak one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a video on youtube of an inhabitant of Cusco, Peru, talking about quinoa.**

- ['Quinoa from a native speaker'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6L218_jZspY)

Although the speaker does not say what their language is, I think it's fair to assume their pronunciation reflects the local Quechua pronunciation. You'll note they pronounce 'quinoa' with three syllables s something like: [ˈkinəˌwa:].

**The first video also notes the two syllable pronunciation:**

- The Origin of Quinoa, (Folktale), [Youtube Video @ 3:31](https://youtu.be/7dmjOjoog4A?t=211)
- Documental: Quinua y Kiwicha, Cultivos con historia (Amaranto), [Youtube Video @ 5:42](https://youtu.be/r-AXHXp5eT4?t=342)

Of course there's no reason why everyone should be trying to say it the same as in Quechua!

Comment: Actually, it's more likely that this is Spanish. Accent is regularly on the penult in Cuzco Quechua and [o] only exists as a lower allophone of /u/ next to a uvular.

Comment: Thanks @user6726! I guess I took a punt counting on that video being correct.

Comment: Please go ahead and modify the link @elikakohen.

Answer (score -1):

I realized that the simplest thing to do is look for the Quinoa wiki entry -- [in Quechua](https://qu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinwa). They give < kinuwa, kinwa, kiwina, kiwna > to which one should add < kiwña > from Cusihuaman's dictionary. So there are no wrong pronunciations, it seems.